# Шашки javascript, клиент и сервер

Tags: javascript, node.js, клиент-сервер, express

Интересует как создать веб приложение шашки, чтобы двое человек могли играть друг против друга по сети, клиент и сервер, c использованием  javascript, node js, express. Кто нибудь знает где можно посмотреть материалы по этой теме? Спасибо!

Comment: У вас смысл просто передавать текущее поле, например как json объект + узнавать о ходе соперника. По сути это простой чат, к вашему списку добавьте socket.io